# Android - ListView и Set

Tags: android, listview, java

Пытаюсь наполнить `ListView` элементами из `SharedPreferences`, делаю это так:

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
s = shpf.getStringSet("data", null);

ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.lvi, s));
```

Но компилятор выдаёт ошибку, мол `Set<String>` нельзя впихнуть в `ArrayAdapter`. Как исправить/переделать код, чтобы не ругалось на это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
s = shpf.getStringSet("data", null);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(s);
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.lvi, list));
```

Comment: @Suvitruf, спасибо за быстрый и правильный ответ!

Comment: @SuperCreeper нет проблем (;